# ElasticSearch: Finding documents with multiple identical fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index with lots of documents in it. There are roughly 20 fields on the data model; of these, there are 5 that, if they are the same, would lead me to conclude that the document is a duplicate. So basically, I want to group documents that have the same values in all 5 fields, and return the documents in each resulting bucket (not just aggregated values).

Can ElasticSearch do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the short answer is yes, elasticsearch can definitely do this, the how can be seen with the following short example:

```
{
  "filtered": {
  "query": {
    // Your query goes here
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['field1'].value ==  doc['field2'].value ==  doc['field3'].value ==  doc['field4'].value"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I've only tried this with 2 fields but I think it should work for more than that as well.

You're basically using filters to remove documents where those fields aren't all equal to each other. Hopefully this helps.

In case you want to match documentA with documentB and see if 5 of their fields are the same then that would be a different problem.

To solve that problem my suggestion would be to write a script which gets one document at a time and then do an elasticsearch query filtering on the fields you're looking for and see if any other documents turn up. If they do, remove them and repeat the process. Move on the next document if there are no matches. When there are no more documents to check, you're done. (you might want to keep a document counter or list of document names to keep track of when you're done)

This is probably not the clean elasticsearch approach you were looking for and there might be a better way but this is one way to solve your problem.

Comment: The drawback of this would be that since you're doing scripting, its more likely to be CPU intensive so you might not want to keep running this all the time.

Comment: Hey Vishal, thanks for your help. This does address something I was curious about -- checking for duplicate values in fields within the same document. However, in this case I need to check for duplicate values in the same field in different documents--for instance, if Doc A has the same FirstName, LastName, Birthday and ZIP Code as Doc B, I would consider the two docs to be duplicates.

Comment: That is definitely one way to do it. I'm also finding that I can do this type of check with lots of nested "terms" aggregations, and a "top_hits" at the bottom of the nest(s)--which, under the hood, pretty much works the way you describe, I think.

Comment: I suppose you could, it just seemed easier this way but maybe the way you're suggesting would be better performance wise considering its built into elasticsearch. Please do post your answer if you get it working, I'm actually curious now about how this could be solved using inbuilt functions :D

Comment: So - I think I like your idea. It's a good pattern that can be adapted for lots of "joining the table back on itself" type operations. Will post some sample code once it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using following steps.

1. Filter out all the distinct values across all the fields using terms aggregation on all fields.
2. Query each value  using should queries on all fields
3. Set min_should_match parameter to 5

As you can see at least 5 fields should have that value for a document to be returned. Have a look in the first example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

To get complete document inside a bucket use top hits aggregation as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)